# I am something pleasing to everyone. What am I?

Tags: riddle

I am something that can be pleasing to everyone,
Yet I may not be loved by all.
I can relieve you from the heat,
But I'm still sold to the community.
I am sold almost everywhere,
But not just anywhere.
I come in many flavors; a wide variety.
But I also come in a slim variety.
**What am I?**

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE :)

Answer (score 2):

My initial guess, though it doesn't fit perfectly:

> An Ice Cream Bar

"I am something pleasing to everyone, Yet I may not be loved by all."

> The first part doesn't work as well, but most people like ice cream, while some do not "love" it.

"I relieve you from the heat, But I'm still given back to the community."

> Ice cream cools you down, but if it's an ice cream bar, the stick can be composted to "give back".

"I am sold almost everywhere, But not just anywhere."

> Most places, at least in the western world, have ice cream, (it's everywhere) but that doesn't mean you can get it at any store. It has to be a store that sells ice cream.

"I come in many flavors; a wide variety. But I also come in a slim variety."

> Ice cream has many flavors, but there are also "slim" varieties that either are lower calorie (healthier/slimmer), or are physically slimmer bars. Those "slim" varieties are just a few of the many overall varieties.

Comment: That's a fitting answer. I'm beginning to edit my riddle in hopes to eliminate other plausible answers. If you look at my answer, please share how to improve the riddle and/or answer. :-)

Answer (score -3):

The answer is:

> **lemonade**

I am something that can be pleasing to everyone,
Yet I may not be loved by all.

> It can be pleasing as a thirst quencher on a hot day, but not everyone likes lemonade.

I can relieve you from the heat,
But I'm still sold to the community.

> It can relieve you from heat (thirst quencher), and lemonade is most commonly known to be sold in small stands within the seller's community.

I come in many flavors; a wide variety.
But I also come in a slim variety.

> Lemonade is always made with lemons, some kind of sweetener, and water, but each there are many different recipes with their own altercations and additions.

Comment: Too late to fix now, but for the future, it's generally **not a good idea to self-answer a riddle so quickly**. It's only been an hour, and you already got one answer; some riddles go days or weeks before being answered, and others gather 10 or more answers before the right one comes along. Be patient, and add hints to your question if necessary, but posting the answer this quickly is jumping the gun. [Sort-of related meta post.](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5231/5373) Just something to remember for future puzzles :-)

Comment: You should answer each part of the riddle like @DqwertyC does in his answer, tip and after the tip the spoiler.